# Intercepting pretty URLs in Laravel4

Tags: laravel-4, url-routing

I am trying to implement a talking url scheme in laravel4 for SEO purposes.

What I have in my routes.php is this:

```
Route::get('{url}', array('as' => 'prettyurl', function($url) .........
```

which works for URLs such as

```
mywebsite.com/this-is-my-fancy-url-about-foo
mywebsite.com/bars
```

but doesn't for those such as

```
mywebsite.com/bars/this-is-my-fancy-url-about-foo
```

it seems that laravel splits the URL according to / before parring it to individual routes.

I could do something like

```
Route::get('{prefix}/{url?}', array('as' => 'prettyurl', function($prefix, $url) .........
```

but it seems a little contrived.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to make it catch everything (including the slashes).

```
Route::get('{url}', ['as' => 'prettyurl', function($url)
{

})->where('url', '.*');
```